# Cannot change Target Runtime when publishing to Azure from VS

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I have a ASP.Core RC2 project (.NET 4.5.1 framework is used) that should be deployed on Azure as x86 Web-Site.

On Publish Setting tab in VS there are the following values:

- Target Framework: .NET Framework 4.5.1
- Target Runtime: Inferred Runtime (win7-x64)

What I want to change is the value of "Target Runtime" to x86 platform, but this combobox is inactive (grey).

Current project.json:

```
{
"version": "1.0.0-*",

"dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms": "1.0.1-*",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
},

"commands": {
  "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
},

"buildOptions": {
  "emitEntryPoint": true
},

"frameworks": {
  "net451": { }
},

"publishOptions": {
  "include": [
    "appsettings.json",
    "project.json",
    "web.config",
    "NlogWeb.config"
  ]
},
"tools": {
  "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "imports": "portable-net45+wp80+win8+wpa81+dnxcore50"
  }
},
"scripts": {
  "postpublish": "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%"
}
}
```

Comment: Post your project.json. Do you have the runtime-identifier for win7-x86 in it?It should say `"runtimes": { "win7-x64": { }, "win7-x86": { } },`. If you only have `win7-x64` then nuget won't restore the necessary packages (for selfcontained applications https://dotnet.github.io/docs/core-concepts/app-types.html)

Comment: I've added project.json content. There is no 'runtime' section, will try with it.

Comment: @Tseng thanks, adding "runtimes" works for me. Please post your comment as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you're developing self-contained applications, you have to add all required runtimes to the `project.json` file, so that nuget/`dotnet restore` can download the runtime files on restore.

Adding the `win7-x86` runtime to the `project.json` should do the trick.

```
"runtimes": {
    "win7-x64": { }, 
    "win7-x86": { } 
}
```

When you target portable apps, you don't need the runtimes section but you have to install the runtime yourself on the target machine. See [.NET Core App Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/app-types) documentation for a more detailed description on how portability types work and are configured.

Comment: @Chet: I've updated the link. The old github documentation was taken down, when .NET Core hit RTM. It's now located on MSDN