# asp.net core 1. how change the Target Runtime to x86

Tags: ms-access, 32-bit, asp.net-core-1.0

i develop an Asp core web application (.net framework). 
how i specify a run as 32-bit applications?

the publish wizard do not give way to change the `Target Runtime`, which the selected option is x64 is selected.

I installed on my machine the x86 version of .NET Core Installer.

publish wizard screenshot:
[image]

***PS Why do I need x86.***

*I had to run the site on a computer that installed Microsoft Access 32-bit (2003, for an old software).
I also need to access data in Microsoft Access file, which requires me to use the Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 driver.*

*The problem is, probably, that the app's core ASP.NET always running as 64-bit applications, is what gives me the known exception 'driver not registred'
stil after set "enable 32-bit application" in IIS.*

*i cant install the 64-bit access driver engine, because it requires the removal of MS Access 32-bit...*

Comment: When you searched the web before posting your question did you see [this thread on GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1624)?

Comment: @GordThompson i see, but in fact I did not know what to do ... I also installed the x86 and still do not have an option to publish as x86

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37944221/191148) you need to add the `"runtimes"` key to your `project.json` file like below image.

Once you do this, the `Target Runtime` entry in `Publish` menu will list all of your specified runtimes. Although this is not enough to get it working since using the `Publish` menu and selecting `x86` version will have no effect and will result in `x64` binary files. (This bug may be fixed in future).

The workaround is to navigate to your project folder where the `project.json` resides. Open a command prompt and type the following to have your binary in desired runtime:

> `dotnet publish --runtime win7-x86`

If you get any error yet, you may need to have the corresponding runtime installed (Download form [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download)).

More info:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/app-types
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/rid-catalog#what-are-rids

[image: .NET Core Project.json Runtimes]

There is also a `platform` key under `buildOptions` listing all possible targets, but yet because of some issues (like [#1624](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1624)) it has no effect and it seems the system ignores that.

[image]